# como hacer para que obtenga fecha y hora automaticamente en web2py

Tags: date, web2py

tengo un campo asi en la tabla:

```
Field('f_fecha', type='date', requires=IS_DATE(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví. Tenía que usar `request.now` para darle un valor por defecto con el tiempo actual:

```
Field('f_fecha', type='date', default = request.now, readable=True, writable=False,
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el código, y dale el formato correspondiente. Por cierto, si sos el autor de la pregunta, solicitá [combinar tus perfiles de usuario](/contact). Luego, acepta tu respuesta.